# .htaccess IF url contains "blog", then execute rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If the url contains the word "blog", then the following block should be executed in .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

I've tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/blog` at the top, but that fails.

PS:

I added

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_rewritten} !=1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /%1/$1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(js)/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(?:/([^/]+))?$ $2?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA,E=rewritten:1]
```

Which makes it so when for example you go to `example.com/fr` it acts like `example.com/index.php?lang=fr` (except if it's `example.com/js...` as written in the rules)

Comment: Move your last in the `/blog/.htaccess` (create it if not there already)

Answer (score 1):

No point adding it at the top. RewriteConds only applies to the following RewriteRule. You can do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog(?:/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

I took the first `RewriteBase` line out since it only applies for relative substitutions, which you're not using here.

Looks like this is set up to be in a .htaccess file in your `/blog/` directory, in which case what I've added is not needed anyway. That first line needs changing if you're moving it to root. Guessing a bit here based on your other post around same issue.

Comment: Hi, now when I go to a blog url for example `example.com/blog/2017/01/18/some-blog-post/`, it says `The requested URL /example/blog/index.php was not found on this server.`

Comment: But it was working before with the RewriteBase rule. Problem is it doesn't play well with other rules I added, I just updated the post.

Comment: The RewriteBase wouldn't cause a problem, it just wasn't doing anything at all, which is why I suggested removing it. What is `/example/blog/` you must have another rewrite or something for that to be getting in there.

Comment: `example` is the folder name in the structure if for instance my site was `example.com`

Comment: There's no .htaccess file in the blog dir either - htaccess is in the root dir.